# Lightweight eye care program

Tags: windows, gratis, health

I'm looking for a good lightweight program which forces me to have my eyes relaxed from time to time after working with computer.

- It is preferred if it blacks out the screen for a while from time to time, e.g. every 30 mins for about 5 mins.
- Taking care of the eyes while working computers is the concern of the question, not exercising on the desk at the office.
- It is highly suggested if it provides some exercise for the eyes — and not for the whole body — in the breaks.

It should run on Windows. It should be lightweight so that it runs well on startup. It should be free of charge (it doesn't matter whether it is open source or not).

Comment: Is it a program that shows special patterns on the screen to "massage" your eyes? Or is it a kind of program that forces you to leave the computer for 2 minutes for instance?

Comment: I prefer something which blacks out and locks the screen for a while from time to time, but those forcing me to massage my eyes or look at somewhere faraway are good, too.

Comment: By the way, welcome to Software Recommendations! Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information then fix your question as it lacks many important things, thanks!

Comment: Those "important things" Nicolas mentioned are e.g. basics such as what OS it should run on, or what exactly you expect such a program to do (log you out, shutdown the computer, refuse to have it restarted until you've slept for at least 6 hours?), what your budget is (how much you are willing to spend, or must the software come for free). The more specific you are, the better answers can be fitted to your needs.

Comment: even though it doesnt technically force you off your computer, id suggest taking a look at [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/). its fully automatic, adjusting your screen brightness based on your timezone. you can even add more settings and modify existing ones. having very low settings tends to make me want to leave my computer for a bit.

Comment: Tnx. I'm already using f.lux, but I get so involved in work that I forget to relax my eyes. I wear glasses already, and I just don't want my eyesight becomes poorer :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) Script below. When running, it turns off the monitor for 5 minutes every 30 minutes. Any keyboard or mouse input will wake up the screen, though this can easily be made not to happen. The script can be compiled into a .exe executable so that you can also share it with friends/collabs and/or set it to run at startup.

```
Loop
{
     Sleep (30 * (60 * 1000))
     SendMessage, 0x112, 0xF170, 1,, Program Manager 
     Sleep (5 * (60 * 1000))
     Send, {LWin down}
     Send, {LWin up}
}
```